# Code only on the selected page - function.php

Tags: wordpress, function

I wonder if it is possible to set in function.php that a given code is called only on a specific page - order summary or cart - at the end of the body section.

Thanks to this, I could use variables available only on this page or only global ones?

Answer (score 0):

welcome to StackOverflow, please use the below code to run any PHP code or insert any other code with the page URL or slug as a condition.

1. To use the page slug as a condition:

   global $post;

   $post_slug = $post->post_name;

   $condition = ($post_slug == 'cart');
2. To use woocommerce page as condition use this code:

   $condition = is_cart();
3. Check if the current page is a product page:

   $condition = is_product();

Finally, use one of the conditions and run your code with the below code:

```
if($condition){
   /* place your code here */
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I only have a question about woocomarka, is there a list of variables somewhere and can I make loops with the list of products in the basket or after placing the order? 
Because I would need to throw it into a code like this: `<script>
    wph('track', 'ViewContent', {
        'content_type': 'Site',
        'content_name': 'ProductList',
  contents: [{
   id:  'PRODUKT_ID1',
   name:  'NAZWA_PRODUKTU1',
                        category: 'KATEGORIA_PRODUKTU1'
   ean:  'PRODUKT_EAN_ID1',
   price:  20.15,
   in_stock:  true
   }]
    })
</script>`

Comment: @Eryk do you want to target a specific product? what variables do you need for the condition?

Comment: I need products list. Basicly - id, name, price, querency, category etc. of product in bascket and thank you page